# Update Listener Like Android Gmail

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener

I have a listview that i show post on it.
what i want is a listener when user moves his finger down and listview can't scroll.(Like Update Listener On Gmail Android App Inbox that when you move your finger from top to down it updates Inbox).

How Can I Do That?

Comment: Do you mean like *swipe to refresh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting is a SwipeRefreshLayout, which is in the google v4 support libraries.

In order to use it, you need to wrap your scrollable layout in `<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>` tags. You can then create a listener for when someone swipes to refresh in the code for your activity

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

....

@Override public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

More info can be found [on this website](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/), and on [this page here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) on Google's developer pages.